# Evaluation of integral with parameters

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am trying to solve the following integral having two strictly positive parameters:

```
Integrate[(u - 1)^2 * (1 - u^(-1/xi))^(k - 3) * u^(-3/xi - 3), 
 {u, 1, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {xi > 0, k > 0}]
```

but the returned solution only holds for $k > 2$.

If I integrate the same expression by making separate assumptions on $k$ (that is, first I integrate assuming $k > 2$, then I integrate assuming $k = 2$ and so on ...), I am able to get a solution for $k=1$, $k=2$ and $k>2$. But when I run

```
Integrate[(u - 1)^2 * (1 - u^(-1/xi))^(k - 3) * u^(-3/xi - 3), 
 {u, 1, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {xi > 0, 0 < k < 1}]
```

Mathematica returns the same unevaluated expression. The same happens when I integrate the expression assuming $1<k<2$.

Additional attempts:
I tried to solve the integral by first applying the function `FullSimplify` but nothing changes. I also developed the term `(u - 1)^2` and multiplied each of its element for `(1 - u^(-1/xi))^(k - 3) * u^(-3/xi - 3)` to find out that the integrals do not converge on `{1, Infinity}` for `0<k<1` nor for `1<k<2`.

How can I solve the integral for $0<k<1$ and $1<k<2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us investigate the behavior of the integrand as $u\to 1$

```
Series[(u - 1)^2*(1 - u^(-1/xi))^(k - 3)*u^(-3/xi - 3), {u, 1, 2}, 
Assumptions -> {xi > 0, k > 0}] // Normal
```

> `(-1 + u)^(-1 + k) xi^(3 - k)`

and as $u\to \infty$

```
Series[(u - 1)^2*(1 - u^(-1/xi))^(k - 3)*u^(-3/xi - 3), {u, Infinity,   2}, 
Assumptions -> {xi > 0, k > 0}] // Normal
```

> `u^(-3 - 3/xi) (1 - 2 u + u^2) (1 - u^(-1/xi))^(-3 + k)`

The above results prove the convergence of the integral under consideration if `xi > 0, k > 0`.

In view of it we may consider

```
j = Integrate[(u - 1)^2*(1 - u^(-1/xi))^(k - 3)*u^(-3/xi - 3), {u, 1,  Infinity},
 Assumptions -> {xi > 0, k > 0},  GenerateConditions -> False]
```

> `xi (2/(k (2 - 3 k + k^2)) +  Gamma[-2 + k] (-((2 Gamma[3 + xi])/Gamma[1 + k + xi]) +  Gamma[3 + 2 xi]/Gamma[1 + k + 2 xi]))`

Numeric calculations

```
N[j /. {k -> 1/2, xi -> 1/10}]
```

> `0.00127714`

and

```
NIntegrate[(u - 1)^2*(1 - u^(-1/xi))^(k - 3)* u^(-3/xi - 3) /. {k -> 1/2, xi -> 1/10}, {u, 1, Infinity}]
```

> `0.00127714`

confirm it.

Comment: It should be noticed that `Limit[j, k -> 1, Assumptions -> xi > 0]` produces `xi (-((2 Gamma[3 + xi] (-1 + EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, 2 + xi]))/
      Gamma[2 + xi]) + (Gamma[
       3 + 2 xi] (-1 + EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, 2 + 2 xi]))/
    Gamma[2 + 2 xi])`.

Comment: What about integer `k<2` ? `Gamma[]` is `ComplexInfinity` on negative integers, so the `Gamma[-2 + k]` part would be problematic for integer `k<2`. I suppose it does not matter too much though since `k` can take on any other non-integer value

Comment: Thanks @user64494 for your help.
If you showed that the integral converges for $xi>0, k>0$, why does Mathematica return the same solution only for $k>2$ when `GenerateConditions` is put equal to `True`?
In addition, if I need to evaluate `j` in $k==1$ I can't because of the indeterminate form. Is it correct in this case to use the value returned by `Integrate[(u - 1)^2 * (1 - u^(-1/xi))^(k - 3) * u^(-3/xi - 3), {u, 1, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {xi > 0, k == 1}]` in order to evaluate the solution in $k==1$?

Comment: Try taking limits as k aapraches 1 or 2. It looks like there might be singular terms that cancel.